# Bah! I keep getting this encoding error in rails with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use rails 3.1.1 with ruby-1.9.2-p290 on a debian system through rvm.
I use swedish letters in my views and in the mysql database.
I keep getting

> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

when I visit a page that get's stuff from the db.

in my database.yml i have this:

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql
  database:something
  encoding: utf8
  username: something
  password: something
  host: localhost    

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database:something
  encoding: utf8
  username: something
  password: something
  host: localhost
```

my config.ru:

```
Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Someappname::Application
```

my environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
Someappname::Application.initialize!
```

my config/initializers/encoding.rb:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

I have tried with all combinations of "Encoding.default_xxxxxx = Encoding::UTF_8" and without them to

Every controller, helper and mailer starts with:

> # encoding: UTF-8

In mysql :

> mysql> show variables like 'char%';

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

And the output from:

> mysql> show variables like 'colla%';

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
```

Any idea of what I can do? I'm strating to get really tired of this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okey, seems that I managed to solve the problem!
The problem was that I was using mysql and mysql2 at the same time.
So to solve it, I had to delete mysql and grab the mysql2 "0.3.7" or else devise was throwing strange errors at me.
And then I had to change the adapter in database.yml to adapter: mysql2

Hope this helps someone having the same problem!